# RxJava: how to split Single

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

How to split a Single stream into separate Single streams, so I can do the following without computing `getUserId()` twice?

```
// getUserId() returns Single<String>

getUserId().flatMap { getSomething(it) }  // Return Single<Something>
getUserId().flatMap { getSomethingElse(it) } // Return Single<SomethingElse>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cache the result of `getUserId` using `cache`

```
val userIdCached = getUserId().cache()
userIdCached
    .flatMap { getSomething(it) }
    .subscribe(...)
userIdCached
    .flatMap { getSomethingElse(it) }
    .subscribe(...)
```